# Probability of transfers

Tags: probability

Probability of transferring materials between containers.

Comment: First, you need to find the chance that 3 whites, 2 whites 1 green, 1 white 2 green or 3 greens are transfered from the first pot, then use your knowledge of conditional probability to determine the rest. you dont need to use the binomial expansion per say, but it will help you in determining the probabilities from the first jar to the second jar

Comment: Concerning your first question: the fact that the drawn marble was firstly transported to a second jar (together with $2$ other marbles) is totally irrelevant. The probability that it is green is just $\frac{4}{12}=\frac{1}{3}$

Comment: Right I have that it is 1/3. But I am not sure how to approach the second part.

Comment: Answer on the second part is: $\frac{8}{11}\times \frac{7}{10}=\frac{28}{55}$. It comes to solving: if one green one is drawn and I draw $2$ others, then what is the chance that both are white. The chance that the first is white is $\frac{8}{11}$ and if the first is indeed white then the chance that the second is also white is $\frac{7}{10}$.

Answer (score 1):

Define the random variable: $X=$ is the number of green marbles drawn, which has the [hypergeometric distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution) with parameters $N=8+4=12$, $K=4$ and $n=3$. Then you have that the probability mass function of $X$ is equal to:  $$P(X=k)=\frac{\dbinom{4}{k}\dbinom{8}{3-k}}{\dbinom{12}{3}}$$ for $k=0,1,2,3$. So, by substitung in the above formula we find that: $$P(X=0)=\frac{14}{55}, P(X=1)=\frac{28}{55}, P(X=2)=\frac{12}{55}P(X=0)=\frac{1}{55}$$

1st Question. Define the event $G$ the marble drawn from the second jar. According to the [Total Probability Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability) you have (by conditioning on X) that:

$$\begin{align*}P(G)&=P(G|X=0)P(X=0)+P(G|X=1)P(X=1)+P(G|X=2)P(X=2)\\&\quad+P(G|X=3)P(X=3)=\\&=0P(X=0)
+\frac{1}{3}P(X=1)+\frac{2}{3}P(X=2)+1P(X=3)=0+\frac{1}{3}\frac{28}{55}+\frac{2}{3}\frac{12}{55}+\frac{1}{55}\\&=\frac{1}{3}\end{align*}$$

2nd Question. You want to calculate the probability: $P(X=1|G)$. According to [Bayes theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem) you have that: $$P(X=1|G)=\frac{P(G|X=1)\cdot P(X=1)}{P(G)}=\frac{\frac{1}{3}\frac{28}{55}}{\frac{1}{3}}=\frac{28}{55}$$

Comment: Ok so the probability that the first marble drawn from the second jar is green is 1/3. But how do I apply this to the second part?

Comment: @Nicholas Is it ok so? Do you understand it? It is a typical exercise in Law of Total Probability and Bayes' theorem. The denominator in Bayes theorem is calculated by the total probability law. So these exercises are very common in that order (first question use Total law to calculate something and then second question use it as denominator in bayes theorem)

Comment: Correct and educational. But also much more complicated than necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The situation sketched in the question is equivalent to the one sketched here:

> $3$ marbles are drawn from a jar that contains $8$ white and $4$ green marbles and the color of the marble that is drawn firstly is checked.

Questions are:

1) What is the probability that the checked color is green? Immediate answer: $\frac{4}{12}=\frac{1}{3}$.

2) If the checked color is indeed green then what is the probability that the color of the other drawn marbles is white?

If the checked color is green then after the first draw $11$ marbles were left in the jar from which $8$ are white. So the probability for the marble drawn secondly to be white is $\frac{8}{11}$. Under the assumption that the second has indeed color white  the probability that the third is white also is $\frac{7}{10}$. So the probability that both are white is $\frac{8}{11}\times\frac{7}{10}=\frac{28}{55}$. This answers 2).